# Using Rstudio to build R packages

Tags: rstudio, r-package

I am using RStudio to build a R package. I am able to create a New Project -> R package -> Package name and add R files. This then creates all the appropriate folders with the R files and the .Rd files in the man folder.

I want to know how I can add 
1) new R files to the package and 2) recreate the package with the new .Rd files.

I find there is no option to refresh the workspace with new files. I have been creating new packages with the new files and then copying over the R & .Rd files to the original project.

Is there a way. Do let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create `.R` files manually and save them in folder called `R` in the main directory of your package (e.g., `my-package/R`).
2. Use `roxygen2` package to create `.Rd` files and other documentation.

You may find helpful information how to create R packages here: [R packages by Hadley Wickham](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)